# Sending data via ajax post using if statement

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Actually I'm pretty new in `jquery` but I try to found if there is a way to achieve what I am looking for

actually here is my code:

```
saveData = function(){
$.post('server/admin.php', { 
    data: 1,
    user: userName
    }, function(response) {
        if(response == 1){
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

}

what I try to achieve is to have multiple different data set with the same function example

```
saveData = function(source){
$.post('server/admin.php', { 
       if(source == 1){
          data: 1,
          user: userName
       }
       if(source == 2){
         data: = 2,
         date: newDate
       }
    }, function(response) {
        if(response == 1){
            location.reload();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
});
```

}

as you can see in what I try to do is to send different data via post not always using the same `$_POST` value in `case == 1` I send user in `case == 2` I send date

Is it possible to achieve something like that without having to write a new function in `jquery` for every form I write if they go to the same processing file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
  saveData = function(source){
    var sendData  ={};

    if(source == 1){// do the if outside of the ajax function
            sendData = {  data: 1,
              user: userName };
           }
           if(source == 2){
            sendData = { data: 2,
             date: newDate};
           }

    $.post('server/admin.php', sendData , function(response) {
            if(response == 1){
                location.reload();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: yes this work but leave me with one problem the first example send data like user=username and the second one send data like data['user']=username but i wont be able to get $_POST['user'] with the second one :(

Comment: because you don't have a username in the second data object, if you want you can append the user property if you really need it